# Multiple VideoCapture on one camera

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture

I might have more than one VideoCapture for a Camera. Unfortunately sometimes the connection to the camera seems to get terminated.

Example:

```
Mat img;
VideoCapture v1(0);
v1.read(img);      //img is a valid picture
VideoCapture v2(0);
v1.read(img);      //img is a valid picture
v2.read(img);      //img is a valid picture
v2 = v1;
v2.read(img);      //img is not a valid picture. Connection seems to be closed
```

Is this correct behaviour, or is it a bug in OpenCV?

Is there a way to check if a particular devicenumber is already open and get the responsible class?

Pseudocode:

```
Mat img;
VideoCapture v1(0);
VideoCapture v2 = alreadyOpen(0);

alreadyOpen(0){
    if(VideoCapture(0).isOpen()){ //how do i check that
        return "v1"               //how do i know where v1 is
    }else{
        return VideoCapture(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you try to explain, why you'd want 2 seperate captures for the same device in the 1st place ? this seems to be quite odd.

Comment: I stumbled upon this when i was debugging some input/output to save the state of some classes. There i had VideoCaptureVector and did something along the lines of `VideoCaptureVector[0] = VideoCapture[0]`, although `VideoCaptureVector[0]` already had an open link to device 0.

Comment: Why would you do that? there's no good reason to do that once you can copy the image to another location and have as many copies as you want.

Comment: You can only have one open handle per device. I cant think of a reason you would ever need 2 VideoCapture objects for the same device, just take a copy of the mat

Comment: @JamesBarnett: Well i can have v1 and v2 both accessing Device 0. The reason was debugging. Since VideoCapture even has a `refcount` i assumed that it would use that...

Comment: Fair enough, although I don't think its really intended to be used that way. As for getting an already open VideoCapture object for a given device, I don't know of any way to do that using the api. I guess you could create a wrapper class for VideoCapture that saves the device id on creation and have a method to return the instance for a given id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Comments:

It's not possible, it might be a bug/not clear if the behavior of OpenCV is intentional.